# How can I use geom_segment with ggtern?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I am trying to generate a ternary plot with arrows showing the shift in composition from time period 1 to time period 2. I know you can do this in ggplot using `geom_segment`, which the ggtern website lists it as an approved geometry.

When I try to run it, however, I get the error `Ignoring unknown aesthetics: z and zend`. Is this an issue with the package, and is there a workaround?

```
ggtern(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = v1_t1, xend = v1_t2, y = v2_t1, yend = v2_t2, z = v3_t1, zend= v3_t2), arrow = arrow())
```

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you move your `aes(x = v1_t1, xend = v1_t2, y = v2_t1, yend = v2_t2, z = v3_t1, zend= v3_t2)` into the ggtern() function? I.e. `ggtern(df, aes(x = v1_t1, xend = v1_t2, y = v2_t1, yend = v2_t2, z = v3_t1, zend= v3_t2)) + geom_segment()`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is just a warning. But besides of that `geom_segement` seems to work fine. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data best shared using `dput()` or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset, e.g. I tried using the default example data from http://www.ggtern.com/d/2.2.0/ggtern_package.html

Comment: Thank you, jared_marmot, moving the aes to the ggtern() call stopped the error. And stefan, you were right- I didn't think it was plotting at all because of a previous plot I had mistakenly rendered that looked very similar to the geom_segment() outcome. Turns out it is not the best way to visualise this data! Apologies for the silly question. Thanks for your replies!